# using 值得 in a phrase

Tags: usage, cantonese, colloquialisms

I have seen the usage of 值得 (deserving) in the following way (Cantonese, colloquial)

值得一來
值得買

I wanted to ask why there is a '一' in the first phrase, and not 值得一買?

What other alternatives are there to say: 這個地方值得一來?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 這個地方值得一來?

it’s not colloquial lah

what we say in cantonese would be:

呢 [nei1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/nei1.Mp3) 個地方值得去 (that place is worth to go)

呢度值得嚟 [lei4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/lei4.Mp3), or [lai4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/lai4.Mp3) (this place is worth to come)

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

##### 你值得更好的（nǐ zhí dé gèng hǎo de）

Situation: When your friend has a lover that is not good enough, you can tell him/her that you deserve better(你值得更好的)

##### 这是一个值得记住的日子（zhè shì yī gè zhí dé jì zhù de rì zi）

The meaning of this sentence is that this is a day worth remembering

Answer (score 1):

Question:-

**(1)  "I wanted to ask why there is a '一' in the first phrase, and not 值得一買?"**

It is used, (please see, https://blog.sparksine.com/kindle)

There is also 值得一看, (worth having a look)

However, separately, "一來" is also a compound commonly used as:-

"一來..." (Firstly...),

"二來..." (Secondly...),

"三來..." (Thirdly)...

**(2)  What other alternatives are there to say: 這個地方值得一來?**

How about, 這個地方值得一游, (This place is worth visiting / touring)

Finally, there is a subtle difference in usage between "worth" & "deserving"

If you wish to say something is "worth" buying or visiting because of some intrinsic / inherent value which you want to seek or obtain, then, the word to use is 值得, (worth it)

If you wish to say a particular situation or someone is "deserving", that is, is "worthy of your attention or assistance", then the word to use is 应得

So, when you say in your question, "I have seen the usage of 值得 (deserving) in the following way....", the bracketed term should have been (worth)

I know that in English, "deserving" and "worth" are often used interchangeably.